# Search Core Data Entity Records with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have implemented a table view which lists data from Core Data Entity. I have bunch of data (about 6000+ records - static data) stored in Core Data. Now I would like to implement search within the table view with NSFetchedResultsController.

One of the column (attribute) in my DB has a long string (separated by space -like a sentence). I would like to implement a beginswith for each word in that sentence - my app should list the db record if one of the word beginsWith search word.

For example, here is my data sample:

Record 1 - Hello Hi Hello How Are you
Record 2 - Hi Hello
Record 3 - Test Hi

Now if I search for 'Hello', it should list Record-1 and Record-2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", searchText];
[[_fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setPredicate:predicate];
[[_fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setFetchLimit:50];
```

Or if you will use Search Result controller

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    NSInteger searchOption = controller.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex;
    return [self searchDisplayController:controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:searchString searchScope:searchOption];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    NSString* searchString = controller.searchBar.text;
    return [self searchDisplayController:controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:searchString searchScope:searchOption];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString*)searchString searchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {

    NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
    if ([searchString length])
        if (searchOption == 0) // full text, in my implementation.  Other scope button titles are "Author", "Title"
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title contains[cd] %@ OR author contains[cd] %@", searchString, searchString];
        else
            // docs say keys are case insensitive, but apparently not so.
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@", [[controller.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles objectAtIndex:searchOption] lowercaseString], searchString];

    [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }           

    return YES;
}
```